# How to do limit, skip and count on a mongodb runCommand

Tags: mongodb

Before you flame, I know how to get the limit, skip or get the count from regular mongodb queries when using `find` command.

But when using the **geoSpatial** `runCommand` which returns **distance** in mongodb. This doesn't accept skip and count parameters. Does anyone know how it can be done ?

```
db.runCommand({ geoNear : "users", near: [25.081398,55.177263], num: 20, distanceMultiplier: 111.194})
```

note:  For now I'm able to get limit by passing `num` to the query but i want to be able to skip also for paginating.

Comment: my extensive search presented this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3925

Comment: Have the same issue. Wish I knew about these idiosyncrancies before using Mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a option not implemented by MongoDB Yet, I'm closing this question but not erasing since there can be some workarounds or solutions by someone smarter

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3925